# Broken WebGL project building in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

Unity version: 2022.3.18f1
OS: Zorin OS 17 (The error occurs in any non-empty project, and was even on a past Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system)

[error in Unity console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdYEx.png)

In the browser the game gives errors related to unityFramework or lack of wasm file and framework.js

**
What i tried:**
Changing compression type (brotil, gzip, disabled)
Disabling\enabling "Decompression fallback"

All this methods doesn't work